# Eclipse Android plugin does not create all required Folders

Tags: android

I"m using the eclipse plugin to try and write an android app.  I looked online, and there's some folders that eclipse isn't creating (specifically res/).  Because of this, I can't run the program ever.  Any ideas?  I also get these errors:

```
[2012-08-09 12:17:08 - WifiCheck] Could not find WifiCheck.apk!
[2012-08-09 12:17:16 - Wififind] res\layout\activity_wifi_find.xml:0: error: Resource      entry activity_wifi_find is already defined.
[2012-08-09 12:17:16 - Wififind] res\layout\activity_wifi_find.out.xml:0: Originally defined here.
[2012-08-09 12:17:16 - Wififind]       C:\Users\Law\workspace\Wififind\res\layout\activity_wifi_find.out.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2012-08-09 12:17:18 - Wififind] res\layout\activity_wifi_find.xml:0: error: Resource entry activity_wifi_find is already defined.
[2012-08-09 12:17:18 - Wififind] res\layout\activity_wifi_find.out.xml:0: Originally defined here.
[2012-08-09 12:17:18 - Wififind] C:\Users\Law\workspace\Wififind\res\layout\activity_wifi_find.out.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2012-08-09 12:18:04 - Wififind] R.java was removed! Recreating R.java!
[2012-08-09 12:18:04 - Wififind] res\layout\activity_wifi_find.xml:0: error: Resource entry activity_wifi_find is already defined.
[2012-08-09 12:18:04 - Wififind] res\layout\activity_wifi_find.out.xml:0: Originally defined here.
[2012-08-09 12:18:04 - Wififind] C:\Users\Law\workspace\Wififind\res\layout\activity_wifi_find.out.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2012-08-09 12:18:46 - Wififind] res\layout\activity_wifi_find.xml:0: error: Resource entry activity_wifi_find is already defined.
[2012-08-09 12:18:46 - Wififind] res\layout\activity_wifi_find.out.xml:0: Originally defined here.
[2012-08-09 12:18:46 - Wififind] C:\Users\Law\workspace\Wififind\res\layout\activity_wifi_find.out.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2012-08-09 12:18:47 - Wififind] res\layout\activity_wifi_find.xml:0: error: Resource entry activity_wifi_find is already defined.
[2012-08-09 12:18:47 - Wififind] res\layout\activity_wifi_find.out.xml:0: Originally defined here.
[2012-08-09 12:18:47 - Wififind] C:\Users\Law\workspace\Wififind\res\layout\activity_wifi_find.out.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2012-08-09 12:32:55 - WifiCheck] ------------------------------
[2012-08-09 12:32:55 - WifiCheck] Android Launch!
[2012-08-09 12:32:55 - WifiCheck] adb is running normally.
[2012-08-09 12:32:55 - WifiCheck] Could not find WifiCheck.apk!
```

Edit:  There are no xml files. Only the java files called R, MainActivity, and BuildConfig

Comment: i think you are compiling and try to run those layout files, delete all out.xml files and for compiling & running project - right click on project name and then run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there's some folders that eclipse isn't creating (specifically res/)

According to your error log output, `res/` exists. Delete the `res\layout\activity_wifi_find.out.xml` file, and the errors shown where in your log will go away.

Comment: The best way to avoid this error is press the Run button when a Java source file is highlighted instead of an xml file.

Comment: @Krylez: What's odd is that I have not run into the `out.xml` file issue in *ages*. In fact, I just tried to reproduce it now (opened a layout file, pressed Run), and it worked just fine. This definitely used to be a problem just by running, but I suspect there is some other, less frequent cause that tripped up the OP..

Comment: There are no xml files.  Only the java files called R, MainActivity, and BuildConfig.

Comment: @Magn3s1um: That is not what your error log says ("res\layout\activity_wifi_find.xml:0: error: Resource entry activity_wifi_find is already defined.")